# Adding click event listener to elements with the same class

Tags: javascript

I have a list view for delete id. I'd like to add a listener to all elements with a particular class and do a confirm alert.

My problem is that this seems to only add the listener to the first element with the class it finds. I tried to use `querySelectorAll` but it didn't work.

```js
var deleteLink = document.querySelector('.delete');

deleteLink.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var choice = confirm("sure u want to delete?");
    if (choice) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

List:

```php
<?php 
    while($obj=$result->fetch_object())
    {
        echo '<li><a class="delete" href="removeTruck.php?tid='.$obj->id.'">'.$obj->id.'</a>'
            . '<a href="#" class="delete"></a>
                      </li>'."\n";
    }
    /* free result set */
    $result->close();       
    $mysqli->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 168, accepted):

You should use `querySelectorAll`. It returns NodeList, however `querySelector` returns only the first found element:

```
var deleteLink = document.querySelectorAll('.delete');
```

Then you would loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < deleteLink.length; i++) {
    deleteLink[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        if (!confirm("sure u want to delete " + this.title)) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
}
```

Also you should preventDefault only if `confirm === false`.

It's also worth noting that `return false/true` is only useful for event handlers bound with `onclick = function() {...}`. For `addEventListening` you should use `event.preventDefault()`.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Rc7jL/3/

---

**ES6 version**

You can make it a little cleaner (and safer [closure-in-loop wise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)) by using [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) iteration instead of for-loop:

```
var deleteLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.delete');

Array.from(deleteLinks).forEach(link => {
    link.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        if (!confirm(`sure u want to delete ${this.title}`)) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

<sub>Example above uses [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) from ES2015 standard.</sub>

Comment: i tryed that but it didnt work i did for(int i=0...)deletelink[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();

         var choice = confirm("sure u want to delete?");
            if (choice) {
                 return true;
             }
            });

Comment: Take a look at the demo I've set up.

Comment: i guess i did same thing worng when i did it the first time thx u :))

Comment: Another neat trick is using the [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) operator which works on array-like objects. So instead of `Array.from(deleteLinks)`, you can do `[...deleteLinks]`. I think `Array.from` is clearer, but just a neat thing worth pointing out.

Comment: why not directly using `deleteLinks.forEach` instead of `Array.from(deleteLinks).forEach` ?

Comment: @OlivierBoissé Because `forEach` is a method of Array. And when this answer was written NodeList didn't implement it. And even now it will not work in older browsers like IE something (11?).

Answer (score 69):

The problem with using `querySelectorAll` and a `for` loop is that it creates a whole new event handler for *each* element in the array.

Sometimes that is exactly what you want. But if you have many elements, it may be more efficient to create a single event handler and attach it to a container element. You can then use `event.target` to refer to the specific element which triggered the event:

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains("delete")) {
    var title = event.target.getAttribute("title");

    if (!confirm("sure u want to delete " + title)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
});
```

In this example we only create one event handler which is attached to the `body` element. Whenever an element inside the `body` is clicked, the `click` event *bubbles up* to our event handler.

Comment: It might be better to attach the click event to the actual parent container element instead of body.

Comment: Typescript 3.2.4: `(event.target as Element).classList`

Answer (score 50):

A short and sweet solution, using ES6:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.input')
      .forEach(input => input.addEventListener('focus', this.onInputFocus));
```

Answer (score 7):

You have to use `querySelectorAll` as you need to select all elements with the said class, again since `querySelectorAll` is an array you need to iterate it and add the event handlers

```
var deleteLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.delete');
for (var i = 0; i < deleteLinks.length; i++) {
    deleteLinks[i].addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var choice = confirm("sure u want to delete?");
        if (choice) {
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This answer is a bit old (3.5 years old), but I must rectify that `querySelectorAll` doesn't return a `Array`, but a `NodeList`, which looks like a `Array` but doesn't have the same methods.

Answer (score 3):

(ES5) I use forEach to iterate on the collection returned by querySelectorAll and it works well :

```
document.querySelectorAll('your_selector').forEach(item => { /* do the job with item element */ });
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by adding some methods to the NodeList prototype for doing this.
I know this question is old, but this way works really well.

I created a tiny project for this purpose: https://github.com/pejman-hkh/nodelist

In this example, I add all events and the each function to the NodeList prototype.

```js
NodeList = window.NodeList;

NodeList.prototype.each = function (callback) {
    this.forEach(function (elm, index) {
        callback.call(elm, elm, index);
    });
    return this;
};

["focusin", "focusout", "load", "beforeunload", "unload", "change", "click", "dblclick", "focus", "blur", "reset", "submit", "resize", "scroll", "mouseover", "mouseout", "mouseup", "mousedown", "mouseenter", "mousemove", "mouseleave", "contextmenu", "wheel", "keydown", "keypress", "keyup", "select"].forEach(function (name, index) {

    NodeList.prototype[name] = function (callback) {
        this.each(function (elm, index) {
            this.addEventListener(name, callback);
        });
        return this;
    }

});

document.querySelectorAll('.delete').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var choice = confirm("sure u want to " + this.innerHTML + "?");
    if (choice) {
        return true;
    }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="#" class="delete">Delect1</a>
    <a href="#" class="delete">Delect2</a>
    <a href="#" class="delete">Delect3</a>
</body>

</html>
```