# Make onclick work on all list elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, onclick

Currently the page only works for the first list item. I want the `onclick` show/hide to work for all list elements. I tried changing it to get element by class, yag name, but couldn't get it right.

Here is the code:

HTML

```
<ul>

  <li id="virsraksts" class="slid">
    <h3>{{ post.date | date: "%B %d, %Y" }}: {{ post.title }}</h3>
  </li>
  <div id="kontents" class="storijs">
    <div style="height:20px;"></div>
    {{ post.content }}
    <div style="height:20px;"></div>
  </div>

  <li id="virsraksts" class="slid">
    <h3>{{ post.date | date: "%B %d, %Y" }}: {{ post.title }}</h3>
  </li>
  <div id="kontents" class="storijs">
    <div style="height:20px;"></div>
    {{ post.content }}
    <div style="height:20px;"></div>
  </div>

  <li id="virsraksts" class="slid">
    <h3>{{ post.date | date: "%B %d, %Y" }}: {{ post.title }}</h3>
  </li>
  <div id="kontents" class="storijs">
    <div style="height:20px;"></div>
    {{ post.content }}
    <div style="height:20px;"></div>
  </div>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.storijs {
    display: none;
}

.para {
    display: block;
}
```

JS

```
document.getElementById("virsraksts").onclick = function() {
  myFunction()
};

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("kontents").classList.toggle("para");
}
```

Comment: Give them all same class name and use loop over HTMLCollection to attach event to all of them. Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21700364/javascript-adding-click-event-listener-to-class/21700383#21700383

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options by either using tag name or class. I have created a simple [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mmLvs1za/) to achieve this.

Basically you can capture all the `li` elements using

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('li')
```

This will return an array of all the `li` elements. Next you iterate this array binding your click handler.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('li')
for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++)
    elements[i].onclick = myFunction;
```

This will now fire the myFunction on click of each `li` element in the array. Finally your function (handler) can use the `this` keyword to toggle the class as:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('li')
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
  elements[i].onclick = myFunction;

function myFunction(e) {
  this.classList.toggle('para');
}
```

Comment: Hello, Im trying out this solution, while it now works for all list items, it doesn't apply the display: block; for all the divs under the list items.

Comment: as far as I understand,  this.classList.toggle affects the <li>, however, the element with the toggling is the child <div>