# Opening Modal from multiple div elements

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

How can I get all my other .open-img elements to open my modal?

Eventually I want to trigger modals with the image inside, I'm sure I should be using .this, but cant get it to work.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/Middi/pen/EWxKLZ

Javascript

```
var modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
var modalBg = document.querySelector(".modal-bg");
var closeButton = document.querySelector(".close-button");
var openImg = document.querySelector(".open-img");

closeButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  modal.classList.toggle("closed");
  modalBg.classList.toggle("closed");
});

this.openImg.addEventListener("click", function() {
  modal.classList.toggle("closed");
  modalBg.classList.toggle("closed");
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21700364/javascript-adding-click-event-listener-to-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to insert `eventListener` on your each `open-img` element.

```
for (var i = 0; i < openImg.length; i++) {
   openImg[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    modal.classList.toggle("closed");
    modalBg.classList.toggle("closed");
   })
}
```

or use **ES6** feature **`Array#from`**:

```
Array.from(openImg).forEach(v => v.addEventListener('click', function(){
    modal.classList.toggle("closed");
    modalBg.classList.toggle("closed");
}));
```

**[Codepen link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/evYzBE)**

Comment: Amazing, So i just needed to iterate through the classes to attach an event listener. 

Thank you @Kind user. That will definitely help me in the future too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution based on your code. It's not perfect but it should give you a good starting point:

```
// get all the matching elements
var openImg = document.querySelectorAll(".open-img");

// iterate over them and add the handler for each of them
openImg.forEach(function (image) {
  image.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // append the image to the modal
    document.querySelector('.modal-main').appendChild(image.cloneNode(true))
    modal.classList.toggle("closed");
    modalBg.classList.toggle("closed");
  });
});
```