# How to call a class function in html onclick

Tags: javascript, html

i have multiple button created dynamically from DB which holds id and Value, i have called a class function through `EventHandler` which works only for the first button, How to call class functions from onclick

```
<button data-add-tab id="51200844-100-RP" value="data_source" onclick="chromeTabs.addTab({title: 'New Tab',this.id,this.value,favicon: false});">Add new tab</button>
 <button data-add-tab id="51200520-483-RP" value="data_source1" onclick="chromeTabs.addTab({title: 'New Tab',this.id,this.value,favicon: false});">Add new tab</button>
 <button data-add-tab id="51200884-103-RP" value="data_source2" onclick="chromeTabs.addTab({title: 'New Tab',this.id,this.value,favicon: false});">Add new tab</button>
```

here is my script which works on even handler

```
<script>
  var chromeTabs = new ChromeTabs()
  document.querySelector('button[data-add-tab]').addEventListener('click', _ => {
    chromeTabs.addTab({
      title: 'New Tab',
      id:_.target.id,
      value:_.target.value,
      favicon: false
    })
  })
```

can you please Help me Thanks.

Comment: `querySelector()` selects the *first* element matching the query string. Check out [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), which returns *all* elements matching the query string. Note that you can't chain `.addEventListener` to this. You'll have to iterate and attach them one-by-one, or use *event delegation*. [More information...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21700364/javascript-adding-click-event-listener-to-class)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is its possible to call class function from onclick?

Comment: Yes, but I question why you'd want to. Using inline `onclick` is **never** a good idea.

Comment: but i can call through `onclick="call(this.id,this.value)"` in script as `function call(id,value){chromeTabs.addTab({val1,val2,val3val4}); }` is its possible to avoid call funtion >

Comment: put your script inside a function, and try to call it using onclick="yourfunction()"

Comment: @TylerRoper oh i didnt know that, let me try your way.

Comment: `<button data-add-tab`  is  **data-add-tab** corect html syntax ??

Comment: @MrJ Yes. It's a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

Comment: In this case I think is'n it better to write `<button data-add-tab=""`  ??

Comment: @MrJ I think that's actually worse. If the data attribute is being used as a flag (i.e. *"If this data attribute exists, do X"*) setting a value is misleading.

Comment: i followed your first cooments post @TylerRoper but i could not understand can you please post your answer on your way ?, Many thanks

Comment: @MrJ that would not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your event handler works only for the first button because `.querySelector()` returns only the *first element* matching the selector.

Instead, you can select *all* buttons matching the selector by using [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

You can then use `Array.from( ... ).forEach( ... )` to iterate through the buttons and attach the event handler to each individually.

```
<button data-add-tab id="51200844-100-RP" value="data_source">Add new tab</button>
<button data-add-tab id="51200520-483-RP" value="data_source1">Add new tab</button>
<button data-add-tab id="51200884-103-RP" value="data_source2">Add new tab</button>
```

```
const chromeTabs = new ChromeTabs();
const addTabButtons = document.querySelectorAll('button[data-add-tab]');

Array.from(addTabButtons).forEach(button => { //For each data-add-tab button

  button.addEventListener('click', _ => {     //Add a click handler
    chromeTabs.addTab({
      title: 'New Tab',
      id: _.target.id,
      value: _.target.value,
      favicon: false
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: this is working but the called function seems little modifications to slow down