# How to use event delegation to execute a function based on clicked element's id?

Tags: javascript, html

I've worked with event delegation in the past but for some reason I'm having trouble setting up a single event listener that executes one of three functions depending on the ID of the element clicked.

Here's the code without event delegation:

```
eventListeners: function() {
    document.getElementById("button-1").addEventListener('click', 
function() {
      shuffler.reset1();
      shuffler.displayCards();
    });
    document.getElementById("button-2").addEventListener('click', function() {
      shuffler.reset2();
      shuffler.displayCards();
    });
    document.getElementById("button-3").addEventListener('click', 
function() {
      shuffler.reset3();
      shuffler.displayCards();
    });
```

I've tried using something along the lines of:

```
document.getElementsByClass("button").addEventListener('click', function 
() {
if (event.target.id == "button-1") {
shuffler.reset1();
}
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript adding click event listener to class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21700364/javascript-adding-click-event-listener-to-class)

Comment: `getElementsByClass()` isn't valid JavaScript, maybe you meant `getElementsByClassName()`? You would still have to loop through all elements, because it returns an array-like element.

Answer (score 0):

Attach the listener to the container that contains all buttons. Then, I'd use an object indexed by id, and check if the `id` of the element that was clicked exists in the object - if so, run the function:

```
const fns = {
  'button-1': () => {
    shuffler.reset1();
    shuffler.displayCards();
  },
  // ...
}

document.querySelector('< something that contains all buttons >').addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  const { id } = target;
  if (fns[id]) {
    fns[id]();
  }
});
```

Note that in this particular case, you can use just one function by checking the last number in the ID:

```
document.querySelector('< something that contains all buttons >').addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  const { id } = target;
  if (id.startsWith('button-')) {
    const buttonNum = id.match(/\d+/)[0];
    shuffler['reset' + buttonNum]();
    shuffler.displayCards();
  }
});
```