# Not getting href attribute when clicking on <a> in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-objects

The problem is that I am not getting the href of `<a>` when there is an element inside `<a>` tag :

CODE:

```js
const $elems = document.querySelectorAll('.content-container a')
var elems = Array.from($elems)
elems.map(a => {
    a.onclick = (e) => {
        console.log(e.target.href)
        e.preventDefault()
        // If I press on <a> that has class name 'google', the code console.logs the href, but if I press on <a> that has class name 'vezani-tekst-holder flex-column', it console logs undefined!
    }
})
```

```html
<main id="article" style="padding: 0px !important; margin: 0px !important;">
    <div class="container content-container" style="background-color: white; margin-top: 0px;">
        <div class="grid-right">
            <article class="big-part" id="article-part" style="padding: 0px !important; margin: 0px !important;">
                <div class="post-text-holder">
                    <div class="post-content post-content-holder">
                        
                        <!-- First  a tag, works fine -->
                        <a class='google' href='https://www.google.com'>Hello Google</a>

                        <!-- Second  a tag, gives undefined -->
                        <a href='https://www.facebook.com'
                            class='vezani-tekst-holder flex-column'>\n
                            <img src='https://www.someimage.jpg'>\n
                            <h3 class='pretitle text'>Text Header</h3>\n <h1 class='small-title'>Small text</h1>\n
                        </a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

If I press on `<a>` that has class name 'google', the code console.logs the href, but if I press on `<a>` that has class name 'vezani-tekst-holder flex-column', it console logs undefined!

I have also tried putting:

`console.log(e.srcElement.attributes.href.textContent);`

and

`console.log(e.originalTarget.attributes.href.value);`

I am a beginner when It comes to JS, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding click event listener to elements with the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21700364/adding-click-event-listener-to-elements-with-the-same-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the element against the event in the eventListener.
Another remark, you dont need tu use map. You can use forEach aganis.

```js
const $elems = document.querySelectorAll('.content-container a')
var elems = Array.from($elems)
elems.forEach(a => {
    a.onclick = (e) => {
        console.log(a.href)
        e.preventDefault()
        // If I press on <a> that has class name 'google', the code console.logs the href, but if I press on <a> that has class name 'vezani-tekst-holder flex-column', it console logs undefined!
    }
})
```

```html
<main id="article" style="padding: 0px !important; margin: 0px !important;">
    <div class="container content-container" style="background-color: white; margin-top: 0px;">
        <div class="grid-right">
            <article class="big-part" id="article-part" style="padding: 0px !important; margin: 0px !important;">
                <div class="post-text-holder">
                    <div class="post-content post-content-holder">
                        
                        <!-- First  a tag, works fine -->
                        <a class='google' href='https://www.google.com'>Hello Google</a>

                        <!-- Second  a tag, gives undefined -->
                        <a href='https://www.facebook.com'
                            class='vezani-tekst-holder flex-column'>\n
                            <img src='https://www.someimage.jpg'>\n
                            <h3 class='pretitle text'>Text Header</h3>\n <h1 class='small-title'>Small text</h1>\n
                        </a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 3):

`Event#target` refers to the element that triggered the event. Which is the `<img />` or `<h1 />` or `<h3 />` element in your case.

Try using [`Event#currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) to get the element that has the event listener registered.

```
const $elems = document.querySelectorAll('.content-container a')
var elems = Array.from($elems)
elems.forEach(a => {
    a.onclick = (e) => {
        console.log(e.currentTarget.href)
        e.preventDefault()
    }
})
```